# JS: check if a single character is NOT a whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex

How to check in JavaScript if the specified character is not a whitespace using regex only? Right now I am doing something like the code below with negation `!` but I would like to avoid mixing of two things to avoid confusions.

```
if (!/\s/.test(character))
    console.log('this is not a whitespace');
```

Comment: `/\S/.test(character)` -> this is not a whitespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (/\S/.test(character))
    console.log('this is not a whitespace');
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use the negated set notation in the regex

```
/[^\s]/
```

That will match everything that isnt a whitespace.